# How to center div within another div?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning how to use the position relative/absolute.

However, I've come a little stuck.

I'm trying to horizontally center a div within a div but when I add `margin: 0 auto;` it does nothing.

I've made a [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelT/Q8NVH/)

Or here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-UK">
    <head>
        <link href="DivTest.css" rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
     margin: 0;
     width: 100%;
}

#header{
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 200px;
     background-color: lightgreen;
     margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#outer{
     position: relative;
     width: 800px;
     height: 500px;
     background-color: red;
     margin: 0 auto;

}

#inner{
     position: absolute;
     width: 200px;
     height: 250px;
     background-color: lightblue;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Cleaned up the fiddle a little bit (you don't have to put the whole document in, the HTML window *is* the `body` element): http://jsfiddle.net/Q8NVH/3/

Comment: @JaredFarrish force of habit ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `position:absolute;` property for `#inner`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8NVH/7/

Comment: @JaredFarrish: actually i also created an updated fiddle :) thanks. yours is better... :)

Comment: Ok... Not having any cognitive dissonance on that comment... `;)`

Comment: @naveen that worked – may I ask why I don't need it – i was following: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997895/difference-between-relative-and-absolute] in an attempt to understand positions. How do I keep the light blue box 20px from the top of the red one?

Comment: @naveen actually I think I understand. I add padding to the outer div?

Comment: thats one way of doing it... please try to read box model in css. it will help http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/