# How to center a div within another div

Tags: html, css

I have these two divs and would like to center the one in the other. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="PicturesBackground" style="height:350px; width: 100%; background: green; border-radius:15px;">
<div class="ContentArea" style="height:80%; width:90%; background: blue; margin-top:30px"></div></div>
```

I have tried using margins and padding and it puts margins/padding on the entire thing instead of just the ContentArea Div within th the background div.

Comment: Hi Kevin, please always remember to Google first. `How to center a div within another div` gives plenty of good answers, including [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally) highly upvoted Stack Overflow question. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center div within another div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924553/how-to-center-div-within-another-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this :

```
.ContentArea{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: That centered it horizontally how would I center the box vertically as well? margin-top:auto; and margin-right:auto; doesn't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](http://jsbin.com/ofutat/2/edit):

```
margin: 30px auto;
```

Hope this helps!