# Converting absolute positioning to relative

Tags: css, positioning

I was stupid and built a web widget in jsFiddle using absolute positioning because it was just a quick prototype to show someone how the functionality would work.

Well we decided that we're gonna use it now and I'm having a hell of a time converting the elements to utilize relative positioning. Also, I'm in the middle of trying to convert this to a jQuery UI widget, so I want everything set up so that it just dumps onto the page without issue.

The widget can be seen **[HERE](http://jonathonmoore.com/proto/)**. Basically it's a search box of sorts that will allow some filtering with the left-most button.

The components are as such:

- **#refine**: The left-most button.
- **#refineDropdown**: The drop down menu that appears when you click on the refine button
- **#search**: The input box
- **#dropdown**: The live-type search filtering box
- **#submit**: The right-most search button

**Question:** When creating a widget, should positioning be done relatively or absolutely? If I have multiple instances of this on a page, the position of the dropdowns should be independent of their position on the page, but I don't fully understand positioning and HTML arrangement to get this to work.

CSS:

```
.inline { float:left; }
.clearBoth { clear:both; }
#refine {    
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -3px;    
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background: rgb(238,238,238); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(238,238,238,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(204,204,204,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border-top-left-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #AAA;
    height:12px;
    padding:6px 25px 6px 6px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#666;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #e8eae5;
}
#refine:hover {
    background: rgb(238,238,238); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%, rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(238,238,238,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(221,221,221,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#dddddd',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    cursor:pointer;
}
#submit {
    float: left;
    margin-right:-1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background: rgb(238,238,238); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(238,238,238,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(204,204,204,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #AAA;
    height:12px;
    padding:6px 6px 6px 6px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#666;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #e8eae5;
}
#submit:hover {
    background: rgb(238,238,238); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%, rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(238,238,238,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(221,221,221,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#dddddd',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    cursor:pointer;
}
.refineClicked {
    background:white !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px !important;
    border-bottom:none !important;
}
.arrow-down {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #666;
    right: 7px;
    top: 10px;
}
#search {
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right:-5px;
    padding: 0px 7px 0px 7px;
    border:1px solid #AAA;
    color:#444;    
}
#search:focus { outline:none }
#refineDropdown {
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
    left:30px;
    width:150px;
    max-height:200px;
    background:#fff;
    border-left:1px solid #AAA;
    border-right:1px solid #AAA;
    border-bottom:1px solid #AAA;
    word-wrap:normal;
    overflow:auto;
}

#dropdown {
    top: 76px;
    padding:3px;
    width:200px;
    max-height:200px;
    background:#fff;
    border-left:1px solid #CCC;
    border-right:1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
    word-wrap:normal;
    overflow:auto;
    left: 59px;
    position: absolute;
}
ul {
    list-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;    
}
li {
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
li:hover {
    margin:-1px;
    background:#E5F3FF;
    border:1px solid #3366FF;
    cursor:pointer;  
}
.selected {
    margin:-1px;
    background: #E5F3FF;
    border:1px solid #3366FF;
}
.hidden { display:none }
```

Comment: Why can't you use absolute positioning?

Comment: I might be a little bit blind today, but I can't see that you ask any question.

Comment: There will potentially be many instances of this search box on the page, so I don't want the positioning to be page-dependent. (I also have to convert the id's to classes...but that's besides the point)

Comment: @Jon: Ah yes, the common "position: absolute" misconception

Comment: So absolute positioning is actually correct?

Comment: @Jon: I'm typing out an answer, your answer to that question of mine confirmed that the way you think absolute is wrong

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks. I've never fully understood it and always just kind of 'happened' upon the correct solution with some finagling.

Comment: Absolute positioning is just a tool like any other. It's like years ago when people abused tables, and now everyone is like NO TABLES! Just like tables, absolute positioning has its uses and there is nothing wrong with using it for those. But like any other tool, don't abuse it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between relative and absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997895/difference-between-relative-and-absolute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason you want this to be done with relative positioning is that you believe absolute positioning is always absolute in relation to the page. Surprise: it isn't.

In fact, what it is absolute to is the first parent that has its position attribute set. As such, the simple solution could be to wrap your entire widget into a div and declare the position of that div as relative.

For example:

```
<p>adsadds
   <div class='container'>
       <div class='absolutelyPositioned'>BlaBla</div>
   </div>
sddasda</p>
```

With this css:

```
.container
{
    position: relative;
}

.absolutelyPositioned
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

will have the inner div with "BlaBla" in it position not at (100, 100) of the web page, but of the container div. In other words if I turn `<p>adsadds` into `<p>adsadds <br />` the "BlaBla" will be pushed down as well.

Comment: This helps *immensely*. Thank you. I'll let others chime in with their comments, but I'll give you the credit.

Comment: Also, a tiny follow up question: So then what does "relative" actually imply?

Comment: An absolutely positioned object takes up no space in the "flow of the page", whereas a relatively position object does take up its space and the positioning properties like top and left specify how much the actual content is moved from its original position.

Comment: For example, in the slightly modified version of my example, if we were to do `.absolutelyPositioned {position: relative; top: -1ex;}` instead, the div with BlaBla in it would be placed on top of "adsadds" and the amount it moved upwards would be equal to the empty bit between it and "sddasda"