# Why must each li from the submenus be positioned absolute while its parent must be relative in order for the submenu to drop down?

Tags: css, dropdown

I'm learning CSS, so I began creating a dropdown menu and I have a question. Here is the structure of my nav:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>style 1
      <ul class="sub-menu menu-1">
        <li>uno</li>
        <li>dos</li>
        <li>tres</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>style 2
      <ul class="sub-menu menu-2">
        <li>uno</li>
        <li>dos</li>
        <li>tres</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>style 3 </li>
    <li>style 4 </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Why must each `li` from the submenus be positioned absolute, while its parent must be relative in order for the submenu to drop down?
If I ignore that I get the following (it drops down the whole area of nav, not just the submenu):
[image: Dropdowns the whole area of nav]

But if I set submenu's parent a position of relative, and set the submenu's position as absolute, it works: [image: It works]

I want to understand why this happens, how the absolute and relative positions work altogether to make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between relative and absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997895/difference-between-relative-and-absolute)

Comment: I just wanna know why not using relative and absolute drops down the whole nav while using it just drops down the submenu.

Answer (score 0):

An absolute element is positioned relative to the nearest positioned parent / ancestor. If an absolutely-positioned element has no positioned parent, it uses the document body as reference.