# advantage of using absolute over relative position?

Tags: css

I always hear that the main difference between relative and absolute that  absolute can be placed out of its parent boundary!

if I can do same thing absolute does using relative, so what is the advantage of using absolute over relative>

An example

```css
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
   .first_div {
       width:300px; 
       height:300px; 
       background-color:red;
       margin: 50px auto;  
 
    }
    
   
   
    .second_div {
        width:140px; 
        height:140px; 
        background-color:green; 
         position: relative;
        top: 50px;
        right: 80px;
        
    }
    
    
  
    
</style>
```

```html
<div  class="first_div">
    <div class="second_div"></div>
 

</div>
```

as you see I can place the green square anywhere in the page using relative   same as absolute does

So what's the main advantage of using absolute over relative ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between relative and absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997895/difference-between-relative-and-absolute)

Comment: The _origin_ of a `relative` positioned element is its original position, it is just an _offset_ to is original position. The _origin_ of an `absolute` positioned element is the position of the closest non `static` positioned ancestor.

Comment: if I can do same thing absolute does using relative, so what is the  advantage of using absolute over relative , I'm not asking how it works.

Comment: You **cannot**  do the same thing `absolute` does with `relative`. If you position an element `relative` then it is just a visual offset the element will still occupy the space at its original place, and it will move if it would move at its original position. Elements that are position `absolute` are taken out of the original layout, and are only positioned relative to the offset parent  [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yv5dth7m/2/)

Comment: Yeah yeah that's it  absolute will remove the original space of the container, that's the main difference I didn't notice this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of absolute is that you can easily position your div anywhere you want with "bottom:"";, top:"";, right:""; and left:""; - however this cause problems when you are making responsible websites - unless your absolute element is in a relative element.

Comment: I can place my div anywhere in the page using relative as well.  See the example  you can move it anywhere you want in the page same as absolute  does!

Comment: Thanks I read it and I understand that the absolute position according to the first none static thing. But to make it easier when I should use  absolute  and when should I use relative, because both can do same thing exactly that's what I want to know.

Comment: Well, when relative works, use it. I almost never use absolute. Please consider choosing this as the right answer if you feel it helped you.

Comment: I will choose yours if no one put an answer today. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid both if possible because mobile devices go haywire when you focus on an `input`, for example, that is positioned this way.  The keyboard display pops up and you're input is now covered up and your UI is hosed.

Stick with margin.

Comment: sometime I need absolute or relative to place something on its parent, while margin move things within the parents boundary,  can't move things out of it as positions does otherwise I always use margin and padding.

Comment: Nah.   You'll see.  Try your page on a mobile after using `position`...  ...just tryin to help

Comment: You mean it will move around right? I mean it will change the current position you set. By using relative this issue won't happen. unless  you mean something else I will try to open the site on my phone to see what will happen. Thank you.

Comment: Right.  I did exactly what you are doing already and after hours of pretty'ing it up I decided to check it out on my Samsung phone and when I interacted with `position`ed elements the UI got really ugly.